# check/uncheck the check box only if the confirmation message is true in angular js

Tags: angularjs, checkbox

I am new in angular js. I have a check box when i click on that checkbox a confirmation message will appear. I need to to check or uncheck the check box only if i confirm the confirmation message. How can i do it with angular js.(currently the check box is check/uncheck even if i cancel the confirmation message). This is my check box element.

```
<input type="checkbox" 
    ng-init="checkValue = x.status" 
    ng-model="checkValue" 
    ng-true-value="1" 
    ng-false-value="0" 
    ng-checked="x.status == 1" 
    ng-click="changeStatus(<% x.id %>, 1, checkValue)">
```

And this is my js part

```
    $scope.changeStatus     = function(id, iFlag, checkValue) {    
var confrm          = confirm('Are you sure that you want to do this');
        if (confrm) {
            Data.post('url', param)
            .then(function(data){
                if (data.success == 1)
                    AlertService.setSuccess('Status changed successfully!');
                else 
                    AlertService.setError('Some error occured. Please try again');
            })
        }}
```

Comment: Modify the x.status value in changeStatus function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, and make appropriate changes, change `ng-checked` value to `x.status`

```js
var jimApp = angular.module("mainApp",  []);

jimApp.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.status = true;
    $scope.changeStatus     = function(checkValue) {  
        var r = confirm("Are you sure that you want to do this");
        if (!r) {
            $scope.checkValue = !checkValue;
        }
      }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="mainApp" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  {{checkValue}}
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkValue" ng-checked="checkValue" ng-init="checkValue = status" ng-change="changeStatus(checkValue);">
</div>
```

Comment: I need a confirmation message before checking /unchecking the check box. Now it is happening in the click event itself

Comment: you can use ng-click insted of ng-change @Science

Comment: But where i will write the confirmation message?@Jithin Raju

Comment: @Science inside if condition

Comment: I am sorry. But this is not my problem. When i am using confirmation message even if i click on cancel button, check box will check/uncheck. Actually check box is working with the click event. The above solution is working. But with the confirmation message when i click on both Ok and Cancel button, check box will check/uncheck. (But the ajax fn will work only with the OK button click.)

Comment: @Science thank you thank you, if you have any doubt in angular js u can contact me,  https://in.linkedin.com/in/jihin

Answer (score 0):

just set ng-model value as per your logic and it should work
    $scope.checkValue = 1; if data.success == 1

```
$scope.checkValue = 0; if data.success != 1
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a syntax issue in your code. Change <%x.id%> to x.id

```
 <input type="checkbox" 
ng-init="checkValue = x.status" 
ng-model="checkValue" 
ng-true-value="1" 
ng-false-value="0" 
ng-checked="x.status == 1" 
ng-click="changeStatus(x.id, 1, checkValue)">
```